# Trying to map numerous attributes on a map in MapInfo

Tags: mapinfo

Any help would be much appreciated for the following problem:

Based on grouping postcode sectors together I have created 30 sales areas in the country. These sales areas have been made visible on the map using normal thematic mapping (separate colour for each area to make them easy to differentiate).
For each sales area I want to show the following attributes in the centre of that sales area:

1. Product Market Share - an absolute value
2. Sales Volume - a graphical representation (e.g. size of circle)
3. Target Area - Yes or No
4. Main Competitor - Choice of 3
5. Contract Renewal Date - Choice of 3 (less than 12 months, 12-24 months and more than 24 months)

Does anyone know if this is possible?

My thinking so far, although untested is:

If I can create a point in the centre of each sales area (not sure how to do this though!?), I could use dispersed groups as the font for this point, with 3 squares which are colour co-ordinated to show attributes 3, 4 and 5 above.
If I can create another point next to the first one, I could create a pie chart showing the market share, where the size of the pie chart indicates the volume of sales. This would cover off attributes 1 and 2 above.

Many thanks for any help that can be given!

All the best

Kev

Comment: I would be careful trying to show that much information in one map.  Things could get pretty ugly and hard to read

Comment: IMO it would just be better to have many maps showing one bit of information rather then cramming it all on one.

Comment: Thanks Nathan - I admit it may look too much in which case I will probably lose the pie chart. At this stage I just need to know if it is possible (and especially how I create one point for each sales area in order to use the dispersed groups font)?

Answer (score 0):

Kev,

If you need one area, or a centroid for one area, you will have to create a single area merging postcode sectors by sales district.

I assume that you already have a column in your table identifying the sales area for each postcode sector.

Next step is to use Table > Combine Objects Using Column... to merge records for the same sales areas into a single record and a combined spatial area.

Now you have a table representing the sales area as a single polygon and you have a centroid where you can show your information, too.

Comment: Hi Peter. Thank you so much for your help. I will combine the objects to make a single record. Sorry, but how do I create a centroid so that I can use it to show the attributes? Many thanks. Kev

Comment: Kev, if you just add your combined table to the map, your polygons will have a centroid that you can use - your labels and thematics etc. will be shown at the centroid.

Comment: If you do need a point, run this command: Update MYTABLE Set OBJ = Centroid(OBJ), replace MYTABLE with the name of your combined table

Comment: Thanks Peter - I will give this a try on Wednesday. All the best. Kev